# Need to pass value from <ng-content [value]="Hello World"></ng-content> to parent

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to pass a value from child to parent via ng-content

Parent Component

```
<block-1>
 <block-2 [value]="{{I want this value from child}}"></block-2>
</block-1>
```

Block-1 Component

```
<div *ngFor="let value form values">
   <ng-content {{I want to pass this value to parent {{value}}></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: You want all the values in the footer tag? Your logic seems reversed. You'd better pass the data from the footer to the child component. Can you show us an example with expected output in the footer?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Please provide a Stackblitz with working example code and intentions, because it is hard to understand what your goal is. The `EventEmitter` as suggested in the provided answer is also a very bad idea for this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EventEmitter` with `@Output` decorator to pass data from child to parent.

**ChildComponent:**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() str = new EventEmitter<string>();

  pass(str: string) {
    this.str.emit('Pass this string to parent');
  }
}
```

**ParentComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <h2>Pass data?</h2>
    <app-child
      (str)="onPassed($event)">
    </app-child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  onPassed(str: string) {
    console.log(str);
  }
}
```

Fire the event (`pass()`) when you are looping `<div *ngFor="let value form values">`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Updated my question.